# Can PowerShell 1.0 host a Cmdlet written in .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net-3.5, powershell, powershell-1.0

When I try to load my Snap-In in PowerShell 1.0 it fails with an error stating that my assembly cannot be loaded due to a dependency on .NET 3.5, which is different to the version of .NET that is currently loaded.

Is it possible to work around this and have PowerShell 1.0 load a Cmdlet with a dependency on .NET 3.5, or is the only option to upgrade to PowerShell 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Does this question/answer help at all?  [Using PowerShell with .NET 3.5 runtime/libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521632/using-powershell-with-net-3-5-runtime-libraries)

I'm curious about the answer as well.